# How can I disable logging for specific rule in pfsense

Tags: firewalls

I would like to prevent pfsense logging of the block for the rule below:

```
Rule: 'Block ULA networks from WAN'
Source: my_router_ip:specific_port
Dest: ip:1900
Protocol: UDP
```

Even though I have disabled UPnP discovery from my home wifi router, every hour it sends out 6 requests, which fill up my logs.

I have tried creating a WAN Easy Rule, but the requests are still being logged. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a rule that specificly blocks this kind of traffic. You don't enbale logging for this rule and this rule has to be placed before your block any rule that is generating the log entries.